# Oracle SQL constraint, name entered must be a member

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have created a tennis club database. This database contains the following tables:

The *player* table

```
CREATE TABLE player
(
  member_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  member_name VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE,
  member_address VARCHAR2(300),
  contact_number INT NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CHECK(gender IN('f','m')),
  club_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  county_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  renewal_date DATE,
  m_type VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL CHECK(m_type IN('junior','student', 'senior', 'family', 'associate'))
);
```

This consists of members of the tennis club.

And then there is the *team* table

```
CREATE TABLE team
(
  team_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  club_seeding INT,
  county_seeding INT,
  player1 VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  player2 VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  team_name VARCHAR2(145) NOT NULL
);
```

This is used to enter 2 players to form a doubles team.

My question is how could I create a constraint that only allows players(member_name) from the *player* table to be entered into the *team* table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need create foreign key constraints 
see docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

but in your sample you need change type of `player1` and `player2` columns from `varchar` to `int`:

`sample of alter table statements`

```
-- Create foreign key constraints 
alter table TEAM
  add constraint fk_team_player_1 foreign key (PLAYER1)
  references player (MEMBER_ID);

alter table TEAM
  add constraint fk_team_player_2 foreign key (PLAYER2)
  references player (MEMBER_ID);
```

sample of createing FK contstraints in table

```
CREATE TABLE team
(
  team_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  club_seeding INT,
  county_seeding INT,
  player1 INT NOT NULL,
  player2 INT NOT NULL,
  team_name VARCHAR2(145) NOT NULL

,constraint fk_team_player_1 foreign key (PLAYER1)
  references player (MEMBER_ID)
,constraint fk_team_player_2 foreign key (PLAYER2)
  references player (MEMBER_ID)  
);
```

`if you want to use member names as PK`

```
CREATE TABLE player
( 
  member_name VARCHAR2(70) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE,
  member_address VARCHAR2(300),
  contact_number INT NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CHECK(gender IN('f','m')),
  club_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  county_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  renewal_date DATE,
  m_type VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL CHECK(m_type IN('junior','student', 'senior', 'family', 'associate'))
);

CREATE TABLE team
(
  team_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  club_seeding INT,
  county_seeding INT,
  player1 VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  player2 VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  team_name VARCHAR2(145) NOT NULL

,constraint fk_team_player_1 foreign key (PLAYER1)
  references player (member_name)
,constraint fk_team_player_2 foreign key (PLAYER2)
  references player (member_name)  
);
```

Comment: But member_name would have to be a primary key in order for player1 and player2 to be foreign keys of member_name right?

Comment: you can keep member_id as PK for the table, but add unique constraint to member_name: `alter table PLAYER
  add constraint UNQ_MEMBER_NAME unique (MEMBER_NAME);` ...in terms of size of data and speed of joins - it would be better to use `INT` type for PK and FK keys... same as - if you need change member name in future... you can easy do this in one table, but all references will be as is with no changes

Comment: I would prefer a solution where data types did not have to be changed, if possible..

Comment: in that case - member_id field is not necessary. make `member_name VARCHAR2(70) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` and then `alter table TEAM
  add constraint fk_team_player_2 foreign key (PLAYER2)
  references player (member_name);`